# Is my solution technically plausible in comparison the the model I used?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good evening, beginner here.

I am trying to make a tabbed list from an exercise of a book, this is the exercise: https://eloquentjavascript.net/15_event.html#i_Kk1WKx2anJ
I think i already got a solution, however, the solution that the book gives uses a different approach than mine and because i really don't know that much of web development, i really don't know which one is "better" in the sense that the author's solution might be more secure than mine or that maybe my solution works for the specific example given in the book, but might not be viable when making a web page.

My solution:

```
<tab-panel>
  <div data-tabname="one">Tab one</div>
  <div data-tabname="two">Tab two</div>
  <div data-tabname="three">Tab three</div>
</tab-panel>
<script>
  function asTabs(node) {
    let childNodes = Array.from(node.childNodes),
        paragraph = document.createElement("p"),
        elementNodes = childNodes.filter(node => node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE);

    for(let element of elementNodes){
      let button = document.createElement("button");
      element.style.display = "none";
      button.textContent = element.getAttribute("data-tabname");

      button.addEventListener("focus", event =>{
        event.target.style.color = "red";
        element.style.display = "inline";
      });

      button.addEventListener("blur", event =>{
        event.target.style.color = "";
        element.style.display = "none";
      });

      paragraph.appendChild(button);
    }
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(paragraph, node);
    document.body.appendChild(node);
  }
  asTabs(document.querySelector("tab-panel"));
</script>
```

Author's solution:

```
<tab-panel>
  <div data-tabname="one">Tab one</div>
  <div data-tabname="two">Tab two</div>
  <div data-tabname="three">Tab three</div>
</tab-panel>
<script>
  function asTabs(node) {
    let tabs = Array.from(node.children).map(node => {
      let button = document.createElement("button");
      button.textContent = node.getAttribute("data-tabname");
      let tab = {node, button};
      button.addEventListener("click", () => selectTab(tab));
      return tab;
    });

    let tabList = document.createElement("div");
    for (let {button} of tabs) tabList.appendChild(button);
    node.insertBefore(tabList, node.firstChild);

    function selectTab(selectedTab) {
      for (let tab of tabs) {
        let selected = tab == selectedTab;
        tab.node.style.display = selected ? "" : "none";
        tab.button.style.color = selected ? "red" : "";
      }
    }
    selectTab(tabs[0]);
  }

  asTabs(document.querySelector("tab-panel"));
</script>
```

Both solutions work almost the same, the difference is that the author's buttons work when clicked, mine work when focused or blurred. My fear is that mine might work just for that specific example and not on something bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple stuff are understandable. Composite stuff consists of a large amount of simple stuff interacting with each-other, therefore, understandable.

Since your solution worked after your test it is safe to assume that it is either correct or close to being correct. If you create a real website, then on the long run you will find out whether there were errors in your planning and you will always have a chance to go back to stuff you created and improve it.

Even us, seasoned programmers are occasionally throwing out some of our code, even recent code. Signs of professionalism is to not worry about the unknowns that the future might bring, have the confidence that one will be able to cope with it and have no feelings about completely removing older code that one may have written.

You are now worrying about the future, but that does not help you. While you are worrying about the future you deprive yourself from the satisfaction of having your initial successes and you also do not start working on your next exercise/task.